# Phalcon request with custom filter

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using phalcon 3 and trying to override the default httprequest class and add a default custom filter, something like this:

```
public function getPut($name = null, $filters = null, $defaultValue = null, $notAllowEmpty = false, $noRecursive = false)
{
     return parent::getPut($name, [$filters, function($value){return str_replace(['null', 'undefined'], null, $value);}], $defaultValue, $notAllowEmpty, $noRecursive);
}
```

This way I don't have to add filters to every place (controller) where i use request->getPut('paramname'). But it doesn't work. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If `$filters` is supposed to be an array of functions, you'll need to set `$filters` to an empty array by default and add your custom filter to that parameter:

```php
public function getPut($name = null, $filters = [], $defaultValue = null, $notAllowEmpty = false, $noRecursive = false)
{
     $filters[] = function($value){return str_replace(['null', 'undefined'], null, $value);};
     return parent::getPut($name, $filters, $defaultValue, $notAllowEmpty, $noRecursive);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you're partly right, if it's supposed to be an array of functions, your way should work. But the point of the question is more like that if. I know that it can accept an array of strings as the framework has some built-in filters like 'trim', but I don't know how to add more to that list . So I need the help of someone more familiar with inner workings of phalcon.